# UDP client/server program that communicates over 2 sockets on different IPs and ports

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, fedora

I have one server and one client. The server and client have 2 NICs. This is being developed on Fedora 26.

- Server IPs and ports: 10.0.0.209:21323 (data channel) and 10.0.0.121:8080 (control channel)
- Client IPs and ports: 10.0.0.210:21323 (data channel) and 10.0.0.122:8080 (control channel)

I am sending a buffer from the client containing a packet number (qualitySequenceCounter) and 40 bytes of an encoded audio file (.chn) over my "data channel" 10.0.0.210:21323 -> 10.0.0.209:21323. When the server receives the data, it unpacks the qualitySequenceCounter and the audio data. Then the server is supposed to send the qualitySequenceCounter back to the client over the "control channel" 10.0.0.121:8080 -> 10.0.0.122:8080. The server sends the data over the "control channel" but the client never receives it and just hangs there waiting. I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong.

**Server**

```cpp
// server2s.cpp
// parsing files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//network stuff
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
//#define SOL_IP IPPROTO_IP
#ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#endif
#define sockerrno errno


char szLineBuf[500];

int iNetSock = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequest = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddr, cAddr;
socklen_t iAddrLen = sizeof(sAddr);
socklen_t cAddrLen = sizeof(cAddr);

int perr(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBuf, sizeof(szLineBuf)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBuf[sizeof(szLineBuf)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error: %s\n", szLineBuf);
    return 0;
}


//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// second socket for control channel
char szLineBufCC[500];

int iNetSockCC = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequestCC = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddrCC, cAddrCC;
socklen_t iAddrLenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);
socklen_t cAddrLenCC = sizeof(cAddrCC);

int perrCC(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBufCC, sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBufCC[sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error CC: %s\n", szLineBufCC);
    return 0;
}

// end
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //file I/O stuff
    // this is the char array that we will populate with the control channel counter and audio data
    char buffer[44];
    // buffer used only for audio data to be written to file
    char audioBuffer[40];

    // this is the char array for the control channel counter
    char bufferCC[4];

    // this is for opening the audio file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    // initializing the location of the audio channel read
    long fileLoc = 0;
    // initializing the control channel counter
    int qualitySequenceCounter=0;
    // initializing how we will be able to tell where we are in the audio file; need to add code to loop back to beginning of the audio file once we reach the end
    struct stat results;

    //network stuff
    const char *pszHost = "10.0.0.209";
    unsigned short iPort = 21323;


    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for control channel
    //network stuff
    const char *pszHostCC = "10.0.0.121";
    unsigned short iPortCC = 8080;
    // end
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    


    //open up audio file for parsing
    outFile.open("/home/mode1_received.chn", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    //if the file doesn't open, tell me
    if(!outFile.is_open()){
       std::cout << "Error opening audio file\n";
    }

    if (stat("/home/mode1_received.chn", &results) == 0) {
        // The size of the file in bytes is in
        // results.st_size
        std::cout << "File size:" << results.st_size << "\n";
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "An error occured getting the file length";
        // An error occurred
    }

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddr, 0,sizeof(sAddr));
    memset((char *)&cAddr, 0,sizeof(cAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_port        = htons(iPort);

    struct hostent *pHost = gethostbyname(pszHost);
    memcpy(&sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, pHost->h_addr, pHost->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perr("cannot create socket");


    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSock, (const struct sockaddr *)&sAddr,  
            sizeof(sAddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for CC
    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddrCC, 0,sizeof(sAddrCC));
    memset((char *)&cAddrCC, 0,sizeof(cAddrCC));
    sAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(iPortCC);

    struct hostent *pHostCC = gethostbyname(pszHostCC);
    memcpy(&sAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr, pHostCC->h_addr, pHostCC->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSockCC = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perrCC("cannot create socket for CC: Control Channel");


    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSockCC, (const struct sockaddr *)&sAddrCC,  
            sizeof(sAddrCC)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed for CC"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    // End
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    // divide size of audio file by 40

    while(qualitySequenceCounter < 103574){

        // Get data
        unsigned int n; 
        socklen_t len = sizeof(cAddr);
        //char *pData = &buffer[0];
        n = recvfrom(iNetSock, (char *)buffer, 44,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cAddr, 
                &len); 
        printf("data received\n");        
        memcpy(&qualitySequenceCounter, buffer, sizeof(int));
        memcpy(&audioBuffer, &buffer[4], 40);

        printf("qualitySequenceCounter : %u\n", qualitySequenceCounter);        

        // this copies our counter that we are using for the feedback loop into the 4 byte char array
        memcpy(&bufferCC[0], (char *)&(qualitySequenceCounter), sizeof(int));
        // this sets up the payload for the UDP transmission
        //char *pDataCC = &bufferCC[0];
        // sending the data via UDP
        sendto(iNetSockCC, bufferCC, 4, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cAddrCC, cAddrLenCC);
        printf("data sent back\n");

        // this code allows us to check the counter by printing it to std out
        /*int counterCheck = *((int *)buffer);

        std::cout << "Counter check: " << counterCheck << "\n";

        const char* beg = buffer;
        const char* end = beg + sizeof(buffer);
        while(beg != end)
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*beg++) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
        */
        //printf("qualitySequenceCounter : %u\n", qualitySequenceCounter);

        //if (buffer == NULL)
        //  break;
        outFile << audioBuffer;
        //buffer[n] = '\0'; 
        //printf("Client : %s\n", pData); 
        //printf("Client : %u\n", n);

        // qualcounter is 103574

        // will need to reset the fileLoc counter to 0 once we reach the end of the audio file to loop the demo
    }

    //close output file
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```cpp
// client2s.cpp
// parsing files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//network stuff
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
//#define SOL_IP IPPROTO_IP
#ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#endif
#define sockerrno errno

char szLineBuf[500];

int iNetSock = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequest = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddr;
socklen_t iAddrLen = sizeof(sAddr);

int perr(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBuf, sizeof(szLineBuf)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBuf[sizeof(szLineBuf)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error: %s\n", szLineBuf);
    return 0;
}


//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// second socket for control channel
char szLineBufCC[500];

int iNetSockCC = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequestCC = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddrCC;
socklen_t iAddrLenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);

int perrCC(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBufCC, sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBufCC[sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error with CC: %s\n", szLineBufCC);
    return 0;
}
// End
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //file I/O stuff
    // this is the char array that we will populate with the control channel counter and audio data
    char buffer[44];
    // this is the char array for the control channel counter
    char bufferCC[4];

    // this is for opening the audio file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    // initializing the location of the audio channel read
    long fileLoc = 0;
    // initializing the control channel counter
    int qualitySequenceCounter=0;
    // counter received over control channel CC
    int qualityCC=0;
    // initializing how we will be able to tell where we are in the audio file; need to add code to loop back to beginning of the audio file once we reach the end
    struct stat results;

    //network stuff
    const char *pszHost = "10.0.0.209";
    unsigned short iPort = 21323;


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for control channel
    //network stuff
    const char *pszHostCC = "10.0.0.121";
    unsigned short iPortCC = 8080;
    // End
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    //open up audio file for parsing
    inFile.open("/home/mode1.chn", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    //if the file doesn't open, tell me
    if(!inFile.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Error opening audio file\n";
    }

    if (stat("/home/mode1.chn", &results) == 0)
        // The size of the file in bytes is in
        // results.st_size
        std::cout << "File size:" << results.st_size << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "An error occured getting the file length";
            // An error occurred}

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddr, 0,sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_port        = htons(iPort);

    struct hostent *pHost = gethostbyname(pszHost);
    memcpy(&sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, pHost->h_addr, pHost->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perr("cannot create socket");


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for control channel
    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddrCC, 0,sizeof(sAddrCC));
    sAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(iPortCC);

    struct hostent *pHostCC = gethostbyname(pszHostCC);
    memcpy(&sAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr, pHostCC->h_addr, pHostCC->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSockCC = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perrCC("cannot create socket for Control Channel");
    // End
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    while(qualitySequenceCounter < results.st_size && fileLoc >= 0){
        // will need to open file inside the while loop once we add the control channel feedback, else we need to open all of the different files at once (which might be easier) and switch back and forth between multiple open files
        // this reads in 40 bytes of data and places it 4 bytes into the char array
        inFile.read(&buffer[4],40);
        // getting the location of where we are in the audio file in case we need to switch audio files
        fileLoc = inFile.tellg();
        // this copies our counter that we are using for the feedback loop into the first 4 bytes of the char array
        memcpy(&buffer[0], (char *)&(qualitySequenceCounter), sizeof(int));
        // this sets up the payload for the UDP transmission
        char *pData = &buffer[0];

        // sending the data via UDP
        sendto(iNetSock, pData, 44, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sAddr, iAddrLen);
        printf("data sent\n");

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // second socket for control channel
        // Get data
        unsigned int nCC; 
        socklen_t lenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);
        //char *pData = &buffer[0];
        nCC = recvfrom(iNetSockCC, (char *)bufferCC, 4,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &sAddrCC, 
                &lenCC); 
        printf("data received again\n");   
        memcpy(&qualityCC, bufferCC, sizeof(int));
        printf("qualityCC : %u\n", qualityCC);
        // End
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


        // increment the feedback counter for the control channel
        qualitySequenceCounter++;
        // this code allows us to check the counter by printing it to std out
 /*       int counterCheck = *((int *)buffer);

        std::cout << "Counter check: " << counterCheck << "\n";


        const char* beg = buffer;
        const char* end = beg + sizeof(buffer);
        while(beg != end)
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*beg++) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
  */
        // will need to reset the fileLoc counter to 0 once we reach the end of the audio file to loop the demo
    }

    //close input file
    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a considerable lack of error-checking here on both`sendto()` and `recvfrom()` in both server and client. So firstly you have no evidence that anything ever got even sent.

Comment: I was using wireshark to watch my packets. That was my evidence about what was being sent where. This will always be in a controlled private network with static IPs. Given that, what error-checking would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client never binds `iNetSockCC` to any particular port, so it isn't listening on any particular port. So how can it receive the response from the server? I'm kind of puzzled why you want two pairs of sockets though. Why not just have the server reply to the client by sending back to the source?

Comment: I thought I could bind to both from the server. I commented out the bind to the "control channel" in the server and added it to the client. Now it is working. The reason for the two sockets is because I will be injecting interference/jamming on the "data channel" and will be using the "control channel" to send info back to the client. The client will use that info to switch between different codecs in an attempt to still get the audio through. Eventually, this will be done with different RF transmitters operating on completely different bands. Thanks for your help, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

These are current working versions of the code that solve the question I posted using the advice of David Schwartz (See comments on the question above).

This is being developed on a MacBook Pro using two virtual machines running Fedora 26. Then it is further tested on a private network with separate laptops running Fedora 26. Wireshark and netem have been indispensable.

***Server (s2.cpp)***

```cpp
// Server
// s2.cpp
// Created by JParks on 7/12/19.
// Last edit: Thur, Sept 5, 3:19PM 2019

//parsing files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//network stuff
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <thread>
#ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#endif
#define sockerrno errno


char szLineBuf[500];
char szLineBufCC[500];

//char buffer[44];

// Server data interface: enp0s3
const char *server_data_channel_ip = "10.0.0.209";

// Server control interface: enp0s8
const char *server_control_channel_ip = "10.0.0.121";


// Client data interface: enp0s3
const char *client_data_channel_ip = "10.0.0.149";

// Client control interface: enp0s8
const char *client_control_channel_ip = "10.0.0.232";


// Ports for data and control channels
unsigned short dataPort = 21323;
unsigned short controlPort = 8080;

// Data Socket
int iNetSock = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequest = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddr, cAddr;
socklen_t sAddrLen = sizeof(sAddr);
socklen_t cAddrLen = sizeof(cAddr);

// Control Socket
int iNetSockCC = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequestCC = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddrCC, cAddrCC;
socklen_t sAddrLenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);
socklen_t cAddrLenCC = sizeof(cAddrCC);


int perr(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBuf, sizeof(szLineBuf)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBuf[sizeof(szLineBuf)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error: %s\n", szLineBuf);
    return 0;
}


int perrCC(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBufCC, sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBufCC[sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error CC: %s\n", szLineBufCC);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //file I/O stuff
    // this is the char array that we will populate with the control channel counter and audio data

    char buffer[324];

    // buffer used only for audio data to be written to file
    char audioBuffer[320];

    // this is the char array for the control channel counter
    char bufferCC[4];

    // this is for opening the audio file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    // initializing the location of the audio channel read
    long fileLoc = 0;
    // initializing the control channel counter
    int qualitySequenceCounter=0;
    // initializing how we will be able to tell where we are in the audio file; need to add code to loop back to beginning of the audio file once we reach the end
    struct stat results;

    //open up audio file for parsing
    outFile.open("/home/jparks/Downloads/mode1_received.chn", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    //if the file doesn't open, tell me
    if(!outFile.is_open()){
       std::cout << "Error opening audio file\n";
    }

    if (stat("/home/jparks/Downloads/mode1_received.chn", &results) == 0) {
        // The size of the file in bytes is in
        // results.st_size
        std::cout << "File size:" << results.st_size << "\n";
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "An error occured getting the file length";
        // An error occurred
    }


    //network stuff
    // Data channel
    const char *pszHost = server_data_channel_ip;

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddr, 0,sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_data_channel_ip);
    sAddr.sin_port        = htons(dataPort);

    struct hostent *pHost = gethostbyname(pszHost);
    memcpy(&sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, pHost->h_addr, pHost->h_length);

    memset((char *)&cAddr, 0,sizeof(cAddr));
    cAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    cAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_data_channel_ip);
    cAddr.sin_port        = htons(dataPort);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perr("cannot create socket");


    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSock, (const struct sockaddr *)&sAddr,  
            sizeof(sAddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for CC
    // Control Channel
    const char *pszHostCC = server_control_channel_ip;

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddrCC, 0,sizeof(sAddrCC));
    sAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_control_channel_ip);
    sAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(controlPort);

    struct hostent *pHostCC = gethostbyname(pszHostCC);
    memcpy(&sAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr, pHostCC->h_addr, pHostCC->h_length);

    memset((char *)&cAddrCC, 0,sizeof(cAddrCC));
    cAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    cAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_control_channel_ip);
    cAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(controlPort);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSockCC = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perrCC("cannot create socket for CC: Control Channel");


    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSockCC, (const struct sockaddr *)&sAddrCC,  
            sizeof(sAddrCC)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed for CC"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    //std::thread t1(task1, iNetSock, buffer, cAddr, cAddrLen, qualitySequenceCounter, audioBuffer);

    // divide size of audio file by 320
    // audio data file size: 4142984 -> divide by 320 to get number of packets ~= 12,945
    // Audio needs to be decoded according to Steve's variation of codec G.711 

    while(qualitySequenceCounter < 12945){


        // Get data
        unsigned int n; 
        //socklen_t len = sizeof(cAddr);
        //char *pData = &buffer[0];
        n = recvfrom(iNetSock, (char *)buffer, 324,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cAddr, 
                &cAddrLen); 

        printf("data received\n");        
        memcpy(&qualitySequenceCounter, buffer, sizeof(int));
        memcpy(&audioBuffer, &buffer[4], 320);

        printf("qualitySequenceCounter : %u\n", qualitySequenceCounter);  


        // this copies our counter that we are using for the feedback loop into the 4 byte char array
        memcpy(&bufferCC[0], (char *)&(qualitySequenceCounter), sizeof(int));
        // this sets up the payload for the UDP transmission
        //char *pDataCC = &bufferCC[0];
        // sending the data via UDP
        sendto(iNetSockCC, bufferCC, 4, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cAddrCC, cAddrLenCC);
        printf("data sent back\n");

        // this code allows us to check the counter by printing it to std out
        /*int counterCheck = *((int *)buffer);

        std::cout << "Counter check: " << counterCheck << "\n";

        const char* beg = buffer;
        const char* end = beg + sizeof(buffer);
        while(beg != end)
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*beg++) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
        */
        //printf("qualitySequenceCounter : %u\n", qualitySequenceCounter);

        //if (buffer == NULL)
        //  break;
        outFile << audioBuffer;
        //buffer[n] = '\0'; 
        //printf("Client : %s\n", pData); 
        //printf("Client : %u\n", n);

        // qualcounter is 103574

        // will need to reset the fileLoc counter to 0 once we reach the end of the audio file to loop the demo
    }

    //close output file
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

***Client (c2.cpp)***

```cpp
// Client
// c2.cpp
// AudioParseSendReflect
// Last edit: Thur, Sept 5, 3:19PM 2019

//parsing files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//network stuff
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#endif
#define sockerrno errno

char szLineBuf[500];
char szLineBufCC[500];

// Client data interface: enp0s3
const char *client_data_channel_ip = "10.0.0.149";

// Client control interface: enp0s8
const char *client_control_channel_ip = "10.0.0.232";


// Server data interface: enp0s3
const char *server_data_channel_ip = "10.0.0.209";

// Server control interface: enp0s8
const char *server_control_channel_ip = "10.0.0.121";


// Ports for data and control channels
unsigned short dataPort = 21323;
unsigned short controlPort = 8080;

// Data Socket
int iNetSock = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequest = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddr, cAddr;
socklen_t sAddrLen = sizeof(sAddr);
socklen_t cAddrLen = sizeof(cAddr);

// Control Socket
int iNetSockCC = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iRequestCC = 1;
struct sockaddr_in sAddrCC, cAddrCC;
socklen_t sAddrLenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);
socklen_t cAddrLenCC = sizeof(cAddrCC);

int perr(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBuf, sizeof(szLineBuf)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBuf[sizeof(szLineBuf)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error: %s\n", szLineBuf);
    return 0;
}



int perrCC(const char *pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szLineBufCC, sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10, pszFormat, argList);
    szLineBufCC[sizeof(szLineBufCC)-10] = '\0';
    printf("Error with CC: %s\n", szLineBufCC);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //file I/O stuff
    // this is the char array that we will populate with the control channel counter and audio data
    char buffer[324];
    // this is the char array for the control channel counter
    char bufferCC[4];

    // this is for opening the audio file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    // initializing the location of the audio channel read
    long fileLoc = 0;
    // initializing the control channel counter
    int qualitySequenceCounter=0;
    // counter received over control channel CC
    int qualityCC=0;
    // initializing how we will be able to tell where we are in the audio file; need to add code to loop back to beginning of the audio file once we reach the end
    struct stat results;

    //open up audio file for parsing
    inFile.open("/home/jparks/Downloads/mode1.chn", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    //if the file doesn't open, tell me
    if(!inFile.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Error opening audio file\n";
    }

    if (stat("/home/jparks/Downloads/mode1.chn", &results) == 0) {
        // The size of the file in bytes is in
        // results.st_size
        std::cout << "File size:" << results.st_size << "\n";
    } 
    else {
            std::cout << "An error occured getting the file length";
            // An error occurred
    }

    //network stuff
    // Data Channel
    const char *pszHost = client_data_channel_ip;

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddr, 0,sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_data_channel_ip);
    sAddr.sin_port        = htons(dataPort);

    memset((char *)&cAddr, 0,sizeof(cAddr));
    cAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    cAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_data_channel_ip);
    cAddr.sin_port        = htons(dataPort);

    struct hostent *pHost = gethostbyname(pszHost);
    memcpy(&cAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, pHost->h_addr, pHost->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perr("cannot create socket");

    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSock, (const struct sockaddr *)&cAddr,  
            sizeof(cAddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // second socket for control channel
    // Control Channel
    const char *pszHostCC = client_control_channel_ip;

    //establish the IP component
    memset((char *)&sAddrCC, 0,sizeof(sAddrCC));
    sAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_control_channel_ip);
    sAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(controlPort);

    memset((char *)&cAddrCC, 0,sizeof(cAddrCC));
    cAddrCC.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    cAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_control_channel_ip);
    cAddrCC.sin_port        = htons(controlPort);

    struct hostent *pHostCC = gethostbyname(pszHostCC);
    memcpy(&cAddrCC.sin_addr.s_addr, pHostCC->h_addr, pHostCC->h_length);

    //creates the UDP socket to send data to
    if ((iNetSockCC = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        return 9+perrCC("cannot create socket for Control Channel");

    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(iNetSockCC, (const struct sockaddr *)&cAddrCC,  
            sizeof(cAddrCC)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    // audio data file size: 4142984 -> divide by 320 to get number of packets ~= 12,945
    // audio is encoded using Steve's variation of codec G.711 


    while(qualitySequenceCounter < results.st_size && fileLoc >= 0){
        // will need to open file inside the while loop once we add the control channel feedback, else we need to open all of the different files at once (which might be easier) and switch back and forth between multiple open files
        // this reads in 40 bytes of data and places it 4 bytes into the char array
        inFile.read(&buffer[4],320);
        // getting the location of where we are in the audio file in case we need to switch audio files
        fileLoc = inFile.tellg();
        // this copies our counter that we are using for the feedback loop into the first 4 bytes of the char array
        memcpy(&buffer[0], (char *)&(qualitySequenceCounter), sizeof(int));
        // this sets up the payload for the UDP transmission
        char *pData = &buffer[0];

    //if(qualitySequenceCounter == 1000 || qualitySequenceCounter == 1001 || qualitySequenceCounter == 1002 ||qualitySequenceCounter == 1003) {
        //  printf("packet 1000 is dropped\n");
        //qualitySequenceCounter++;
    //} else {

        // sending the data via UDP
        sendto(iNetSock, pData, 324, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sAddr, sAddrLen);
        printf("data sent\n");

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(20000000));
        printf("delay over\n");
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // second socket for control channel
        // Get data
        unsigned int nCC; 
        //socklen_t lenCC = sizeof(sAddrCC);
        //char *pData = &buffer[0];
        nCC = recvfrom(iNetSockCC, (char *)bufferCC, 4,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &sAddrCC, 
                &sAddrLenCC); 
        printf("data received again\n");   
        memcpy(&qualityCC, bufferCC, sizeof(int));
        printf("qualityCC : %u\n", qualityCC);
        // End
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //}

        // increment the feedback counter for the control channel
        qualitySequenceCounter++;
        // this code allows us to check the counter by printing it to std out
 /*       int counterCheck = *((int *)buffer);

        std::cout << "Counter check: " << counterCheck << "\n";


        const char* beg = buffer;
        const char* end = beg + sizeof(buffer);
        while(beg != end)
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*beg++) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
  */
        // will need to reset the fileLoc counter to 0 once we reach the end of the audio file to loop the demo
    }

    //close input file
    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```